# Discord py bot using LuckPerms or Tebex to link discord account to minecraft account

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have been creating a discord bot to help with a minecraft server my friends are creating. I am wondering if there is a way to use LuckPerms (the rank plugin we are using) or Tebex (buycraft stuff) to link a discord account with a minecraft account. Then using the linked discord account I want to verify what ranks they have so I can assign them in the discord accordingly. I am pretty new to python and discord bots so any help is welcome!

Comment: Hey, welcome to [so]. This is not a code writing service but a site where you can get help with a specific problem. So what you're looking for is probably to get started with a tutorial on discord.py and go from there.

Comment: I already have the bot mostly done. I am asking specifically for using an API for something like LuckPerms of Tebex to do a specific thing. I have been using stackoverflow for many years (just made a new account)

Comment: You are obviously misunderstanding. If you didn't know you can browse the site without an account with ease. This is the first time I have attempted to get help myself and therefore needed to create an account. However, you are obviously not here to help.